# How to use EPIC DNAm files (.idat) to infer copy number alteration

Tags: r, methylation, copy-number

I have access to EPIC DNA methylation profiles from approximately 40 samples. I want to use these .idat files in order to predict copy number alterations within specific promoter regions of interest. Can you recommend any R packages that could perform this task?

Through research I have stumbled upon epicopy (https://github.com/sean-cho/Epicopy/blob/master/vignettes/Epicopy.Rmd), but I'm uncertain whether this is the best package for this problem.

Cheers,
GB

Comment: This is a good question and very interesting area of investigation. The package you sourced looks okay from my 'outside the field' perspective, but I understand your concerns.

Comment: I am not too familiar with this, but conumee (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/conumee/inst/doc/conumee.html) seems promising